# Why is JavaScript not changing css variable google chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome-extension

I am making a chrome extension, which can be found [here](https://replit.com/@codeitfast/chrome-extension-v003#manifest.json). As you can see in it, I need the javascript to change a variable, which changes another variable on the webpage (It sounds redundant but is necessary).
In my `websiteCss.css` file, I have

```css
:root{
  --bg: #00ff00;
}


body.replit-ui-theme-root.light{
  --background-default: var(--bg);
}
```

And in my JavaScript, I have:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', documentEvents  , false);

try{
  document.getElementById('background').value = "#1BFFFF"
}catch (err){
  console.log(err)
}

  
function documentEvents(){
  var r = document.querySelector(':root');
  
  function reload(){
    var color = document.getElementById('background').value
    r.style.setProperty('--bg', color);


    
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "linear-gradient(to right, #2E3192,  " + color + ")"

    //console.log(getComputedStyle(r).getPropertyValue('--bg'))
    
    if(Math.random(0,1) < .1){
      console.log(color)
    }
    window.requestAnimationFrame(reload)
  }
  
  window.requestAnimationFrame(reload)
}
```

My website/popup is changing its colors to match the new ones, but the website I am editing isn't. Can someone please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where your Javascript is running. The popup has its own HTML, JS, and CSS; so does the webpage itself.

If you are running this in the context of the **popup**, it will only affect the popup styles.

If you run this in the **content** script, you will see the styles change on the webpage.

See https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/#functionality

Comment: I actually am using the content script in the manifest.json file. I am curious, however, if I am allowed to have both the popup and manifest access the same JS file. After all, I need to convert the value from the popup to the website and doing that over multiple files would be challenging. Do you have any idea of what to do?

Comment: I have an input box in my popup, and I need to transfer the variable from that to the css for my website. How would I do that?